# Importing data from Firebird to SQL Server - date and time types

Tags: sql-server, firebird

I'm trying to import data from Firebird database to SQL Server via Firebird's ODBC driver. When I start Import wizard I see that date and time data types are not mapped properly.

[image]

However, if I change manually type 23 and 24 to date and time import process works without any problems. Is there a workaround for this? I need to import some 150 tables ...

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server management studio has mapping definition files, there you can define how datatypes need to be mapped. These files are located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\MappingFiles (on the host where the management studio is installed, not on the server)
See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx

I can't provide you more information than this as I have actually never moved data between Firebird and SQL Server in this way; I hope this does provide a starting point to solve your problem.

Comment: Cool, didn't know that. I'll look into it and report my findings

Comment: Unfortunately none of mapping files there apply to ODBC->SQL transformations. What is even more puzzling is that when you fire up Integration services and create a transformation yourself all data types are correctly recognized.